Black and white comic series about government agents who track down and kill aliens
When I was at school, early 2000s, there was this black and white comic series I would read all the time.
Basically, aliens had invaded earth but had disguised themselves as humans. The main protagonist was a government agent (I think). He and his parter would track down these aliens by asking people random specific questions like "What's your mother's middle name?" and stuff like that. The aliens couldn't answer these questions for some reason. Once they found the alien, they would use these stick things, kinda like a neuralyzer from Men in Black, except they would kill aliens and not wipe their memories.
The protagonist would always go to this bar/diner and speak with the barman either at the start or end of each book (I don't remember).
There was an issue where an alien had infiltrated the headquarters, SPOILERS, it was the janitor and the protagonist's partner didn't want to check him. There was another issue where the barman told the protagonist a story about what he saw then the aliens landed.
Big twist near the end was that several people that the protagonist knew, including his partner, were aliens. He followed his partner to a gathering of aliens and that's how he found out.
That's all I can remember.

Not to ask what might seem like a silly question, but was it The Men In Black comic? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Men_in_Black_(comics)

I just tracked down and read all 6 issues of the original comic, and no what they're describing is a different comic (or they're mixing up details from two or more comics).
